# How to properly write proof to show Cauchy and Convergence at the same time?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, metric-spaces, proof-writing

I am seriously confused about how to write a proper proof that show cauchy and convergence at the same time. This is because there are two $N$s involved. One is that for every $m,n \geq N$ sequence is Cauchy the other is for $n \geq N$, the sequence convergent.

> Show every compact set is complete

**Proof:**

---

Let $A \subset (M,d)$ be a compact set.

Let $(a_n)$ be a cauchy sequence on $A$, such that $\forall \epsilon, \exists N$ such that $\forall n, m \geq N, d(a_n, a_m) < \epsilon$.

Since $A$ is compact, therefore $(a_n)$ has a convergent subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ that converges to a limit $a \in A$.

Then $(a_n)$ converges if $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists N$ such that $\forall n > N$, $d(a_n, a) < \epsilon$. Then $d(a_n, a) \leq d(a, a_{n_k}) + d(a_{n_k}, a_n)$.

***Pick $n_k \geq N$.***

Then $d(a_n,a) < \epsilon.$

QED.

---

**Problem!**

When I wrote "*Pick $n_k \geq N$.* ", which $N$ am I referring to? Did I pick the $N$ such that the sequence is now cauchy, or the $N$ such that the sequence is convergent?

How to fix this proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, none of them. Instead you need to take say $N_1$ and $N_2$, one for being a Cauchy sequence and the other for having a converging subsequence.

Than take $n_k\ge\max\{N_1,N_2\}$ and $n\ge n_k$ to obtain $d(a_n,n)\le2\epsilon$.